# How to use MongoRepository in test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to use a `MongoRepository` in a `@DataMongoTest`. I can't add it in `@ContextConfiguration` since it's an interface.

I ended up doing the following:

```
@DataMongoTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyService.class})
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.exmaple.path.to.mongorepos")
```

which works, but I don't like the fact that I need to set this String value of the base package. Interestingly, `@EnableMongoRepositories` alone doesn't work.

Is there another method to instantiate a `MongoRepository` in a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

try replacing:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyService.class})
@EnableMongoRepositories("com.exmaple.path.to.mongorepos")
```

to:

```
@Import({MyService.class})
```

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: can you paste the directory structure? what was the error?

I got "Unable to retrieve @EnableAutoConfiguration base packages" with `@ContextConfiguration` and without `@EnableMongoRepositories`

replacing both with @Import worked in my test, so I think my setup might be different